# How to reload a webpage once routed to using react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window, reload

Re-asking from a previous questions as this could be a work around.

I have a widget I'm using from a software provider (Mindbody) it needs to load some data using a `<script>` tag which I have in the head of my app. The page is being routed to using react-router-dom. The problem the js data only loads when you refresh the page.

What is a good method to reloading a page as soon as the page is routed to. I tried `window.location.refresh();` but this loads infinite time.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Stack, Box, Typography, Modal, Backdrop } from '@mui/material';
import ButtonV2 from './ButtonV2';
import PurchaseWidget from './PurchaseWidget';

const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  boxShadow: 24,
  borderRadius: 3,
  transition: "5s ease-in-out"
};



    const PurchaseLanding = () => {
    
    
        const [show, setShow] = React.useState(true);
        const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    
    
      return (
        <div>
            <Modal
            open={show}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
            aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
            disableAutoFocus="true" 
            BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
            BackdropProps={{
              timeout: 500,
            }}>
                
            <Box sx={style}>
                <div>
                    {/* full width image */}
                <img style={{borderRadius: "10px 10px 0 0"}} src="https://res.cloudinary.com/djjb1vyjm/image/upload/v1660541084/1_uxhi8p.png" width="100%" alt="" />
                </div>
                <Box p={2}>
                    {/* title */}
                <Typography align="center" id="modal-modal-title" variant="h5" component="h2">
                <span className='space-font-heavy'>Buy your [10-pack]</span>
                </Typography>
    
                {/*  onboarding message */}
                <Stack pb={3} alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" direction="row" spacing={2}>
                    <Typography px={1} align="center" id="modal-modal-description" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                        <span className='space-font-light'>Once completed download the Mindbody app to add, update, and book your workouts!</span>
                    </Typography>
                </Stack>
    
                {/* button group left/right */}
                
                <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                  <ButtonV2 />
                 
                </Stack>
    
                </Box>
            </Box>
            </Modal>
    
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    
    export default PurchaseLanding
```

Comment: You probably wanted to use `location.reload()`. But seems more like a workaround. What does this script do?

Comment: remove the script tag and use states inside the component that is being routed to

Comment: The script tag loads a payment widget for my customers to pay for a service that I sell

Comment: Why not put the `script` tag in your component instead?

Comment: <healcode-widget data-version="0.2" data-link-class="healcode-pricing-option-text-link" data-site-id="30089" data-mb-site-id="686934" data-bw-identity-site="false" data-type="pricing-link" data-inner-html="Buy Now" data-service-id="101165" />
``

Comment: This is in my component, but I created the function in another component called <Button />